# Dummy coding omits / removes select variables from the data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, pca

I have a fairly large dataset **1460(n)x81(p)**. About 38 variables are numeric and rest are factors with levels ranging from 2-30. I am using dummy.data.frame from ***[dummies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dummies/dummies.pdf)** package to encode the factor variables for use in running regression models.

However, as I run the following code:

`train_dummy <- dummy.data.frame(train, sep = ".", verbose = TRUE, all = TRUE)` some of the colums are from the original dataset are removed.

Has anyone encountered such issue before?

Link to original training dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

A number of columns from the original dataset including response variable SalePrice are being dropped. Any ideas/suggestions on what to try?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue. I don't think there is enough info here to reproduce the issue, but I do have a few first thoughts.

#### run dummy data processing before train/test split

I see you're running the dummy data solely on your training data. I've found that it is usually a better strategy to run dummy data processing on the entire dataset as a whole, and then split into train / test.

Sometimes when you split first, you can run into issues with the levels of your factors.

Let's say I have a field called `colors` which is a factor in my data that contains the levels `red`, `blue`, `green`. If I split my data into train and test, I could run into a scenario where my training data only has `red` and `blue` values and no `green`. Now if my test dataset has all three, there will be a difference between the number of columns in my train vs test data.

I believe one way around that issue is the `drop` parameter in the `dummy.data.frame` function which defaults to TRUE.

#### things to check

Run these before running dummy data processing for train and test to see what characteristics these fields have that are being dropped:

```
# find the class of each column
train_class <- sapply(train, class)   
test_class <- sapply(test, class)

# find the number of unique values within each column
unq_train_vals <- sapply(train, function(x) length(unique(x))) 
unq_test_vals <- sapply(test, function(x) length(unique(x)))

# combine into data frame for easy comparison
mydf <- data.frame(
    train_class = train_class,
    test_class = test_class,
    unq_train_vals = unq_train_vals,
    unq_test_vals = unq_test_vals
```

)

I know this isn't really an "answer", but I don't have enough rep to comment yet.

Comment: All the columns that are being omitted are either of numeric or factors class.

Comment: All the columns that are being omitted are either of numeric or factors class.  My code is already checking for class type. for some strange reason, a number of columns are being dropped from the original dataset. The data in the question is just dummy data.